# How to estimate the error on the position of the point x where y is maximal in quadratic relationships?

Tags: statistics, polynomials, error-propagation

I would like to estimate the elevation at which species richness is expected to be maximal. The relationships between species richness ($y$) and elevation ($x$) follows a second order polynomial function:

$$y=a*x^2+b*x+c$$

Using R, I obtained an estimation of the parameters $a,\, b$ and $c$; noted $E(a),\, E(b)$ and $E(c)$; as well as an standard deviation around these estimation $SD(a),\, SD(b)$ and $SD(c).$

Now, I can compute the elevation (`Xmax=x[y=max(y)]`) at which species richness ($y$) is expected to be maximal using:

$X_{max}=-b/(2*a)$ and $E(X_{max})=-E(b)/2*E(A).$

My question is, what is the expected error on $E(X_{max})$ (i.e. $SD(X_{max})$).

I found that $SD(X_{max})$ can be estimate using propagation error estimation:

$$SD(X_{max})=|E(X_{max})|*\sqrt{\frac{V(a)}{E(a)^2}+\frac{V(b)}{E(b)^2}-2\frac{Cov(a,b)}{E(a)*E(b)}}.$$

But what is the covariance $Cov(a,b)$ between the paramerters $a$ and $b$ of second order polynomial function?

If somebody has another idea, I will be happy too!

Best,

Thomas

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE   Please try to use formatting so that your questions are easy to read.

Comment: You could fit directly to $y=a(x-x_0)^2+y_{\text{max}}$.

Comment: I have edited your Question, mainly to use TeX for easier reading. There were a couple of places where your original notation could not have been quite correct and I put what I thought you meant. Please have a look to make sure I have not deviated from what you intended. Please feel free to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to give good advice without more information
about your data. I will give a partial discussion of what I
imagine to be the simplest case for your data and best
solution for what you want to accomplish.

Suppose you observed the number of species $Y_i$ at $n$ elevations $x_i$
along a particular mountain slope, using the model 
$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \beta_2 x_i^2 + e_i,$$
for $i = 1, \dots, n$ and $e_i$ iid $Norm(0, \sigma_e)$.

You will get estimates $\hat \beta_0,\, \hat \beta_1,$ and
$\hat \beta_2$ of the coefficients, and $\hat \sigma^2$ of
the error variance. Getting confidence intervals for
the $\beta_j$ ($j = 0,1,2$) in terms of $\hat \sigma$ and
Student's t distribution is straightforward, but depends
on the normal distribution of the errors $e_i$ in your model
(and the constancy of the variance for different altitudes).

Now it seems you want a confidence interval of the maximum point
$\eta = -\beta_1/2\beta_2$ of the parabolic curve of your model.
A reasonable point estimate is $\hat\eta = -\hat\beta_1/2\hat\beta_2$ (your
$-b/2a$).

However, this estimate does not have a simple
distribution. In practice, I suppose there are two difficulties.
First, even if your errors were normal, the distribution
theory would be messy because, as you note, numerator and
denominator are not independent. Second, in practice, the
errors are unlikely to be normal and finding the distribution
of your point estimate is even further from reach by traditional
methods.)

I think your best bet is to bootstrap the residuals from
your model. If 
$$\hat Y_i = \hat \beta_0 + \hat \beta_1 x_i + \hat \beta_2 x_i^2,$$
is the 'predicted' number of species at the $i$th altitude, then
the corresponding residual is $r_i = \hat Y_i - Y_i.$ If your
model is correct, then the $r_i$ should be a random sample from
a distribution useful for determining your desired CI.

Roughly speaking, the bootstrap procedure would sample $n$ values
$with\; replacement$ from among these $n$ residuals $r_i$.
Call, them $r_i^*$. Then construct re-sampled $Y_i^* = \hat Y_i + r_i^*$.
Rerun the regression with these $Y_i^*$ and the original $x_i$,
to get $\hat \eta^*.$ Repeat this resampling several thousand
times $B$ to get a sequence of $\eta_k^*,$ for $k = 1, \dots, B.$
Their distribution contains the required information on the
variability of your point estimate $\hat \eta$ to permit
construction of a bootstrap CI.

I will not try to give more details here because I don't know
the exact nature of your data. But I think bootstrapping may
be the only reliable way to assess the variability of your
$\hat \eta$, even if your model and data are not exactly as I
imagined.

Note: If you google 'bootstrap regression' you will see quite a variety
of resampling approaches for regression. Resampling can be at
the level of the data, the residuals (as above), or the distributions of the error  and/or
parameters.

Addendum: I did a bootstrap on fake data with $n = 56$ elevations evenly spaced from 1000  to 12000, corresponding $Y_i$ (one per elevation) with
$\beta_0 = 20,\,\beta_1 = 0.013,\, \beta_2 = 1e-06,$ and normal
error with $\sigma_\epsilon = 5$. Hence $\eta = 6500.$ Initial
regression had $\hat \eta = 6551.7.$ A 95% Bootstrap CI: $(6362.1, 6736.8).$ I could post R code and a plot on your request.